# Always have to clean before building in a mix and match Obj C / Swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, build-error, ios-targets

I was wondering if someone knows a workaround around this bug in `XCode`

I have a mix and match `Obj C / Swift` project.

Always when I am changing the target and then build the project I get errors in the file XXX-Swift.h  regarding duplicate `interfaces` and previous declarations.

Then I have to clean and build again in order for it to work.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what is the sequence of events that leads to the errors, but I'm guessing that you are making changes to `'XXX-Swift.h'`. This file is generated by Xcode and you should not make changes to it. (Although I would expect Xcode to just re-create it and discard your changes, rather then throwing errors).

Can you show the errors?

Comment: I´m not changing that file. Basically all the errors are:
- Property has a previous declaration
- Duplicate interface definition for class 'MyClass'
- And finally 'Too many errors emitted, stopping now'

My guess is that the Swift classes need to be converted again to Obj C code when I change targets and therefore it only works when I clean and build after changing targets. 

Hopefully this will get fixed in later versions.

Comment: What do you mean with "changing the target". Also I think xcode shows you the option to unfold the error, and I think it will tell you something like 'previous devlaration found here'. Otherwise you can search for it. Can you show the line where the error occurs and the results of a search for the same method?

Comment: Changing the target in the target dropdown menu right next to the build and run button in the top left corner in XCode. The errors are all in the XXX-Swift.h file. It's probably because XCode does not delete the old file when I build and creates a new XXX-Swift.h file and then complains about duplicate interfaces and previous declarations in that file.

Comment: Do you mean the Schemes dropdown, or the simulator/device dropdown? Changing the scheme results in a build in its own folder, so I would not expect problems. Changing the simulator/device might affect the build architecture, but this also lives in its own folder. Maybe you should check the actual location of the -Swift.h file, see if it is in the same location, and see if there are actual difference. Who knows, maybe some Xcode cache is misbehaving. In that case, you should file a bug with Apple.